# view scrolls down to tabhost when fragment opened

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, android-scrollview

When I open fragment with scrollview and tabhost inside the scrollview, it automatically scrolls down to the start of the tabhost hiding the top part of the scrollview. I've tried changing various things, nothing worked so far. Will keep trying, just throwing this here in hopes someone can help me. Here is the relevant parts of the code.

FragmentProfile.java

```
public class FragmentProfile extends Fragment {
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("", ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_c_text)),
            FragmentProfileTab1.class, null);

    return view;
}
}
```

fragment_profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/scrollview"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:weightSum="4">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="rolands"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="#6e0d16"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="#fff" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

FragmentProfileTab1.java

```
public class FragmentProfileTab1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_tab1, container, false);


    return view;
}
}
```

fragment_profile_tab1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".DeviceFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3000dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#333"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The view atuomatically scrolls down to the start of the tabwidget. I'll keep editing as I try new things.

I tried scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0) and scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP) without success.

Comment: This is what I see when I run your code: "rolands" text, and your tab just under this. Isn't it the same at your screen, too?

Comment: I made the tab with height 3000. For me, when I run the app, it automatically scrolls down to the start of the tab leaving the name rolands out of the screen. I need the view to stay at the top.

Comment: Well, it does not happen in my Nexus 5 emulator.

Comment: I'm testing on Samsung S4 Mini, gona try on different device.